# which index strategy choose for my web application using hibernate search and very huge database?

Tags: glassfish-3, hibernate-search

**what i have :**

1 - big database which is in constant growth.

2 - Web application made in glassfish and hibernate search.

**what's the problems :**

1 - what the best index strategy to use knowing i tried the manuel index and it takes too long each time .

2 - the database is filled also from out of the web application (second application), then automatic index will not index these data

Answer (score 0):

If the database gets changed via another non Hibernate Search application you need to use manual indexing. Have you tried the mass indexer? There are many parameters you can play with to adjust indexing speed. To avoid full re-indexing every time, I recommend to use some sort of timestamp based approach. At least the indexed entity should have a last update column of some sorts which can be queried to determine the entities which have changed since the last index run. Only these entities need to be indexed.

Comment: i used the mass indexer as suggested . i ve implemented a method responsible of indexing which i call from the main application when this one is less used. i did not implemented yet the sort idea which i found very interesting if it permit to win some (memory,cpu,...time).